# Manage Bluetooth Connections with PowerShell

Tags: .net, bluetooth, cross-platform, powershell-4.0

Im trying to find a script that would work to initiate/disconnect bluetooth connections through powershell. Any pointers towards a relevant module or command would be extremeley helpful.

Found some solutions on microsoft technet: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/switch-bluetooth-off-and-on-via-powershell/m-p/2275616

Looked around and found this but decided it had way too much bloat for what I wanted to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.